# What is the correct term for the wafer after Eucharistic consecration?

Tags: transubstantiation

Before the priest performs the Eucharistic ceremony, he holds an object we call a 'wafer'.  After the ceremony is complete, can we still correctly call the object a 'wafer'?  Or can it only be correctly called the 'host'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fr. John Hardon, S.J., [*Modern Catholic Dictionary*](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=34005):

> [HOST](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=34005)
>
> A victim of sacrifice, and therefore the consecrated Bread of the Eucharist considered as the sacrifice of the Body of Christ. The word ["host", with a lowercase "h"] is also used of the round wafers used for consecration. (Etym. Latin *hostia*, sacrificial offering.)

Prior to consecration, at the part of the Holy Sacrifice of the Mass called the offertory, the priest refers to the wafer of wheat as a host (lowercase "h"):

> *[Súscipe, sancte Pater](https://youtu.be/Lq6_qbykTNo?t=77), omnípotens ætérne Deus, hanc immaculátam hóstiam…*
> Accept, O holy Father, almighty and eternal God, this unspotted **host** (victim)…

After consecration, at the [*Unde et mémores*](https://youtu.be/zha8DqKL1QU) prayer, he says, while making five signs of the Cross with his right hand over the consecrated Host and chalice of His Blood:

> *…offérimus præcláræ maiestáti tuæ de tuis donis ac datis, hóstiam ✠ puram, hóstiam ✠ sanctam, hóstiam ✠ immaculátam, Panem ✠ sanctum vitæ ætérnæ, et Cálicem ✠ salútis perpétuæ.*
> …we offer unto Thy most excellent Majesty of Thine own gifts, bestowed upon us, a pure ✠ **Host**, a holy ✠ **Host**, an unspotted ✠ **Host**, the holy ✠ Bread of eternal life, and the Chalice ✠ of everlasting salvation.

<sup>[English-Latin Mass text source](https://isidore.co/divinum/cgi-bin/missa/missa.pl)</sup>

Comment: From the last passage, the object can still validly be called 'bread' after consecration?  If so, is it correct to say: 1. the object is 'bread', also 2. the object is 'God', and therefore 'this piece of bread is God'?

Comment: @yters With a capital "B", as in "Bread of Life" (cf. [John 6:48](https://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=50&ch=6&l=48-#x): "I am the bread of life.").

Comment: Ah, I see, it is a title whose referent is Jesus, no longer the same word as 'bread'.

Comment: @yters Correct.

Comment: Therefore, it is incorrect to say 'this piece of bread is God'.  One can however say 'this Bread is God'?

Comment: @yters That's correct. It's no longer bread.

Comment: Which brings me back to my original question, is it therefore correct to say 'Catholics believe the universe was created by a piece of Bread'?

Comment: @yters "a piece of God" makes no sense; [He's supremely simple](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FP/FP003.html), indivisible.